# How long can anchovies under olive oil stay in fridge?

Tags: food-safety, fish

I have some anchovies dipped in olive oil and parsley. How long can they stay in fridge before going bad?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How long can I store a food in the pantry, refrigerator, or freezer?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer)

Comment: I don't think that the specific mix I asked could be easily found there

Comment: Fabio, there is no specific number for each and every possible combination and it’s not necessary. That’s why we have a generic Q/A. Your dish fits in multiple categories (previously canned protein, opened / herbs in oil / generic “cooked dish”), the shortest time of which should be applied, so 3-4 days. If you notice anything before that, discard anyway.

Comment: No you're wrong Stephie, that's why there's a website to ask new questions. That's how the new questions are made